# c# Regular Expression (RegEX) matched group fails to return a matched character

Tags: c#, regex

The objective of my c# app is to extract 2 decimal values (latitude, longtitude) from a text document. I tried to apply a template to pick up those numerals. It is an older app with Framework-3.5 platform.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

String BB = "<span style=\"font-family:&quot;Times&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;\">\r\n<i>Lat</i>: 29.48434, <i>Long</i>: -81.562445 <o:p></o:p></span></p>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Times&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>\r\n<table class=\"MsoNormalTable\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td style=\"padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt\">\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><b><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Times&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;\">Coordinates:</span></b><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Times&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;\">\r\n<i>Lat</i>: 29.48434, <i>Long</i>: -81.562445 <o:p></o:p></span></p>\r\n</td>";

string p2 = @".*Lat\D+(-*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\D+Lon\D+(-*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)";

Console.WriteLine(p2);
foreach (Match collection in Regex.Matches(BB, p2)) {
    foreach ( Group gp in collection.Groups) {
        Console.WriteLine("Match group {0}", gp.Value);
    }
}
```

I expected the output of Group[2] should have the '-' sign before 81.562445 but it looks like it has dropped it even it matches the template "(-*[0-9]+.[0-9]+)" !!!  Is there anything I can do to make the group show with the '-' sign?

[image: picture of output]

Comment: You do not have text.  You have an html document and should use html techniques instead of regex.  regex is regular expressions and html is not regular.

Comment: Thought about that. Just that I should not assume there's nothing between the HTML tags and the lat-long which means I still have to apply a "regular" template anyway.  Might just have to do it in the first place!  "\D+?\d" is the best covering any possibilities!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is looking for non-digit characters (`\D+`) before the latitude and longitude values and the `-` is not a digit so it is captured.  To make the non-digit match non-greedy, use the a `?` after the sequence (`\D+?`) making your final pattern

```
string p2 = @".*Lat\D+?(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\D+Lon\D+?(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)";
```

As for the comment about parsing the html node instead of matching with a regex, this is generally better but in this case it doesn't really gain you much as the inner text of the relevant elements turn out to be

```
"\r\nLat: 29.48434, Long: -81.562445 "
```

and

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nCoordinates:\r\nLat: 29.48434, Long: -81.562445 \r\n"
```

both of which require similar amounts of massaging to tease out the required data, likely with a regex anyway, unless an exact match can be expected with the remaining content.

Comment: Very nice explanation.  Thankyou!  Now i know what they mean by "greedy" or "hungry" or "devouring"!!!